# Performance of object Creation vs one instance and injecting dependencies each time - JAVA

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns

I am creating a live trading bot in Java and I came across something I need help with.
Every 10ish seconds I get an update on the ticker of the stock, and I have to run this data through an analysis phase to determine if a strategy entry or exit is triggered. My concern is that there could be hundreds of different strategies to be analyzed on each tick, so I am not sure if it is better to have an instance created and stored for each strategy or create an object only for that specific ticker.

A strategy is a specific configuration of ticker, interval, and indicator configuration. So even if the logic of the strategy 1 is the same as the logic for strategy2, I would need different information to analyze them. This is why I could get potentially hundreds of strategies.

I want to see which design could be better:

**Create and destroy the Strategy object each ticker**
I have a Strategy object which I can create and inject all other dependencies, analyze the ticker information and then destroy it with the garbage collector. Meaning I would not be storing hundreds of instances in the memory, but only X amount of them (if multithreading).

**Create a base Object and inject dependencies**
I can create a base object and store it in a map based on the type of strategy, so instead of having hundreds of instances I only have (lets say) 15. Then inject the relevant information of the current strategy I am analyzing at that specific time. I think of this like an object Pool, where I store base instances that can analyze the data by injecting what i need in a functional matter.

**Create an object for each strategy and store it**
For this i would create an instance for each strategy run, and store it in a map. This means I could potentially have hundreds of objects stored in memory, but at least I wont go through the performance cost of creating new object each time.

I am not sure what is best performance wise, and I would like to know what are the disadvantages of recurrently creating and destroying objects in JAVA. I assume that affects performance.

Comment: Hundreds of objects is so few that it practically doesn't matter how you do this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP never returned to follow up on this, and there's only one answer (mine) with a comment on its relevance to OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought i could reach rapidly the Heap memory overflowing.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds a lot like a linear algebra problem.

In one 2x2 matrix you have all the stocks on one side and each strategy on the other. Where they meet is how the stock price will influence the buy/sell decision.

You can then multiply this by a 1d stock prices matrix, and the result with give you the answers according to each strategy.

You might want to look on Github for a Java matrix package. NASA had a good one back in the day.

Comment: How is this related to the OP's question?